# How to disallow a user from deleting a row in a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Assume a datagrid with an ICollectionView as its ItemsSource that allows users to delete/add/edit rows. The question is how to dissallow the user from deleting a row if the value of a cell in the row is of specific value. In otherwords:

```
id   Name    IsSpecial
-----------------------
1    Foo      true
2    Bar      false
```

I would like the user to be able to change the name of Foo but not delete it, as well as not allow the user to change IsSpecial to false on that row. But allow the user the freedom to change any value on any other row where IsSpecial is false

Comment: Set [CanUserDeleteRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuserdeleterows.aspx) to `false`?

Comment: almost... I might be able to bind CanUserDeleteRows to something that determines if the current row 'IsSpecial' but I also need to disallow editing of the IsSpecial column.

Answer (score 0):

If code behind is OK, to prevent an edit use [CellEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending.aspx) event. if you set `e.Cancel=true` It will not commit the edit.

Of course, you want to stop user from deleting a row too. So, My suggestion is to handle [CurrentChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.currentchanging.aspx) event of a ICollectionView and Cancel those changes you want.